# increment the version number and current date in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, version

I need to increment the version number in the particular line in file using batch script, and the version looks like as `1.0.0.00:01.` The increment is only for `":01"` and I want to update the current date in the same file in another line.
please help me to solve this

Comment: is `1.0.0.00:01` always the content of the line.How looks the line with the date? what is the date format? are they always in the same line number? Could you give a content of an example file?

Comment: my file will be like this:
script=01
Date=year.month.date
minorversion=1.0.0.00:01
when i trigger the build the i need the output as:
script=02
Date=currentdate
minorversion=1.0.0.00:02

Comment: and the content is always same @npocmaka

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your file with

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  if "%%a"=="minorversion" (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%x in ("%%b") do (
      set /a incr=%%y+1
      ...
```

and take it from there. the main thing is that you can split each lone with the outer for loop into keys and values and then process those values like you want.

Comment: this is my script@echo off>newfile&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: set up your date here. It probably won't match my format so you'll need to adapt:
set dt=%date:~10,4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims==:" %%a in ("filename") do (
set v= %%b
set v= !v: 0=!
set /a v+=1
set v=0!v!
set v=!v:~-2!
>>newfile echo SCRIPT=!v!
>>newfile echo BuildDates=%dt%
>>newfile echo Version=%%a:!v!
goto :aa
)
:aa
more +3 "filename" >> newfile
del "filename"
ren newfile "filename"